# VBA Code to Autofill

Tags: vba, excel

Have a column `H` with alphanumeric characters. Some cells in this column have the content *(RAM)* followed by 5 digits starting from *00000* to *99999*.
If cell `H219` has the content *(RAM) 23596* then i have to fill cell `A219` with a comment **"completed"**.
This has to be done for all cells with the content "*(RAM) followed by 5 digits*"

```
Sub Macro16_B()
    ' ' Macro16_B Macro ' '
    intRowCount = Worksheets("Reconciliation").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For i = 11 To intRowCount
        If InStr(Range("H" & i).Value, "(RAM 00000-99999") Then
            Range("A" & i).Value = "Completed"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Sub Macro16_B()
'
' Macro16_B Macro
'

'
    intRowCount = Worksheets("Reconciliation").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For i = 11 To intRowCount
    If InStr(Range("H" & i).Value, "(RAM 00000-99999") Then
        Range("A" & i).Value = "Completed"        End If
        Next i

End Sub

Comment: Completely new to coding. hence not sure about my code !!

Comment: If you're trying to find the cells that contain (RAM) then you should change your instr condition to `If InStr(1,Range("H" & i).Value, "(RAM)")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are already 2 good answers, but allow me to paste my code here for good measure, the goal being to submerge @user2574 with code that can be re-used in his/her next endeavors:

```
Sub Macro16_B()
    'In the search spec below, * stands for anything, and # for a digit.
    'Remove the * characters if you expect the content to be limited to "(RAM #####)" only.
    Const SEARCH_SPEC As String = "*(RAM #####)*"

    Dim bScreenUpdating As Boolean
    Dim bEnableEvents As Boolean

    'Keep track of some settings.
    bScreenUpdating = Application.ScreenUpdating
    bEnableEvents = Application.EnableEvents

    On Error GoTo errHandler

    'Prevent Excel from updating the screen in real-time,
    'and disable events to prevent unwanted side effects.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'Down with business...

    Dim scanRange As Excel.Range
    Dim cell As Excel.Range
    Dim content As String
    Dim ramOffset As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reconciliation").Columns("H")
        Set scanRange = .Worksheet.Range(.Cells(11), .Cells(.Cells.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    For Each cell In scanRange
        content = CStr(cell.Value2)
        If content Like SEARCH_SPEC Then
            cell.EntireRow.Columns("A").Value = "Completed"
        End If
    Next

Recover:
    On Error Resume Next
    'Restore the settings as they were upon entering this sub.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = bScreenUpdating
    Application.EnableEvents = bEnableEvents
    Exit Sub

errHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Error"
    Resume Recover
End Sub
```

Comment: Best way to thank us is for you to upvote helpful answers and select the best one with the big green checkmark.

Comment: @ SJR - What if, the string is in multiple columns ??

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the Like operator. The precise format of your string is not clear so you may have to amend (and assuming case insensitive). # represents a single number; the * represents zero or more characters.

```
Sub Macro16_B()
    Dim intRowCount As Long, i As Long
    ' ' Macro16_B Macro ' '
    intRowCount = Worksheets("Reconciliation").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For i = 11 To intRowCount
        If Range("H" & i).Value Like "(RAM) #####*" Then
            Range("A" & i).Value = "Completed"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You're missing the * sandwich around your search string. Edit: unless we're looking for whole cell content, yeah that's possible... OP said "has the content" so I assumed it could contain more than just that.

Comment: @Excelosaurus - yes good point, will wait for clarification from OP.

Comment: "(RAM) 00009 S2X" (This is the precise format of my string).

Comment: I've added an asterisk which should cover the S2X (or anything else after the number).

Comment: "(RAM) 00009 S2X" - the last three characters of the string are alphabets or numbers or alphanumeric. but the first part of string is always (RAM) followed by 5 digits and then last 3 characters changes!!

Comment: @ SJR. Yes i tried & it worked. Thanks much. but a quick question. What if the digits vary from 1-5. eg: if the string is (RAM) 123 S2X or (RAM) 2335 AJQ or (RAM) 1 A etc....

Comment: You could perhaps use "(RAM) #*" which will find (RAM) followed by a number and then anything else. If that won't work you'd probably have to look at using regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

A non-VBA answer could be (if the cell doesn't have extra text other than (RAM) & 5 numbers):

```
=IFERROR(IF(LEN(VALUE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(H1,"(RAM)",""))))=5,"completed",""),"")
```

My VBA answer would be:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rLastCell As Range
    Dim rCell As Range

    With Worksheets("Reconciliation")
        Set rLastCell = .Columns(8).Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
        If Not rLastCell Is Nothing Then
            For Each rCell In .Range(.Cells(1, 8), rLastCell)
                If rCell Like "*(RAM) #####*" Then
                    rCell.Offset(, -7) = "complete"
                End If
            Next rCell
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Cheers @Excelosaurus for heads up on the `*` would've forgotten it as well. :)

Comment: You get my vote for providing 2 ways of doing things and for the pleasure of bumping your rep above 9'000.

Comment: Cheers. Thought I still had a small way to go for 9k. 